# how to properly run a scrapy crawl from cron

Tags: cron

How would I run a command like `scrapy crawl empt.com` in a `cron` job where I need to be in a specific folder to run the command for example:

`/downloads/my_crawler/empt/empt/` then the command `scrapy crawl empt.com`

My current `crontab` entry looks like this:
`0 */2 * * * * root /downloads/my_cralwer/empt/empt/ scrapy crawl empt.com`
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
0 */2 * * * * root cd /downloads/my_cralwer/empt/empt/ && scrapy crawl empt.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following lines in `crontab -e` runs my scrapy crawl at 5AM everyday. This is a slightly modified version of crocs' answer

```
PATH=/usr/bin
* 5 * * * cd project_folder/project_name/ && scrapy crawl spider_name
```

Without setting `PATH`, cron would give me an error "`command not found: scrapy`". I guess this is because `/usr/bin` is where scripts to run programs are stored in Ubuntu.

Note that the complete path for my scrapy project is `/home/user/project_folder/project_name/`. I ran the `env` command in cron and noticed that the pwd is `/home/user`. Hence I skipped `/home/user/` in `crontab` above

The cron log can be helpful while debugging

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but to get mine to work I also needed to add a path variable. Otherwise cron may not be able find scrapy. For me it was:
`PATH=/usr/local/bin`
Just locate the scrapy binary and add the path variable to a location before the cronjob in the file. I usually use `crontab -e` to edit the cronjob list. But utilities like webmin can also do this.